# how to use assert to ignore type but only compare the value

Tags: python, pytest

How can I use assert statement to verify two variable with value only to ignore type? I would like following to return True

```
s = 3
t = '3'
assert s == t
```

Comment: 3 and "3" do not have the same value in the sense that they are stored as the same sequence of bits in memory, even if you disregard any bits having to do with type representation. If that's not what you mean by "value", you should clarify what you mean.

Comment: Without going into details about bits and memory storage, your `s` and `t` don't have "the same value" indeed - one is the integer 3 and the other the character '3'. Type is actually part of the value of an object. In this case you can of course convert one or the other to match types, but this won't work as a generic solution, and there is no possible generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert both to the same type and compare those; i.e.

```
assert str(s) == str(t)
```

Comment: thats the closest thing to a generic solution you are going to find, unfortunately. `float` is a [well documented special case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python) that you would have to handle separately.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: f1 is not equivalent to f2, and str(f1) is not equivalent to str(f2); you consider this a problem?

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry I meant `f2 = 10/3.0` - but redoing the test leads to `str(f1)` being equal to `str(f2)` so I must have done sometjhing wrong indeed ;)

Answer (score 1):

In general, values of different types don't compare as equal unless the `__eq__` method for a type handles the type conversion for you. Neither `str.__eq__` nor `int.__eq__` do this, so both `'3' == 3` and `3 == '3'` will evaluate as False. You will have to convert one or the other of the arguments in order for your assertion work, and the conversion will have to preserve whatever sense of equality you have in mind.

```
assert str(s) == t
assert s == int(t)
```

Types with a properly written `__eq__` method can handle this for you. Imagine such a class named `IntorStr`; then all of the following would pass:

```
for x,y in itertools.product([3, '3'], repeat=2):
    assert IntOrStr(x) == y
    assert x == IntOrStr(y)
    assert IntOrStr(x) == IntOrStr(y)
```

`IntOrStr` might look something like

```
class IntOrStr:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
        self.type = type(v)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.v == other:
            return True
        try:
            v = self.type(other)
        else:
            if self.v == v:
                return True

        try:
            v = other.v
        else:
            return self.v == v or self.v == self.type(v)

        return False
```